# Convert QCOW2 to VMDK (Citrix Xen)

Tags: kvm-virtualization, convert, qcow2

Hy everyone,

the search function does not come up with a propper solution.
I want to convert a old KVM disk QCOW2 to an compatible Ctrix Xen disk e.g. VMDK with that qemu-img converting tool

qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O vmdk /mnt/itstuff/disk.qcow2 /mnt/itstuff/disk_conv.vmdk

but this is not working for me. I got the following error:

qemu-img: Could not open '/mnt/itstuff/disk.qcow2': Invalid argument
qemu-img: Could not open '/mnt/itstuff/disk.qcow2'

Any ideas?

regards Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your source file is present, accessible and not currently used by a running VM, the problem can be due to the source file *not* being a valid Qcow2 one (ie: maybe it is a raw file with a wrong `.qcow2` extension)

Try omitting the source format parameter, issuing `qemu-img convert -O vmdk /mnt/itstuff/disk.qcow2 /mnt/itstuff/disk_conv.vmdk`

If that does not work, please provide additional information by issuing `qemu-img info /mnt/itstuff/disk.qcow2`

Comment: Thanks for your help. File is present, accessible and a copy of that VM (so its not used). I tried your suggestion "qemu-img convert -O vmdk /mnt/itstuff/disk.qcow2 /mnt/itstuff/disk_conv.vmdk
qemu-img: error while writing sector 16384: Invalid argument

Comment: root@kvm01:/mnt/itstuff# qemu-img info /mnt/itstuff/disk.qcow2
image: /mnt/itstuff/disk.qcow2
file format: raw
virtual size: 10G (10737418240 bytes)
disk size: 10G

Comment: Ah I changed the writing path to a local one. Now its running. I´ll keep you updated. Thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: @rcpe so your `qemu-img info` shows you are dealing with a raw file, rather than a qcow2 one.

Comment: @rcpe if so, please mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: I would, but I dont know how to do it :)

Comment: @rcpe well, it is quite simple ;) just click the up arrow left to the the reply to upvote, then click on the "check" symbol just under the down arrow.